# Best practices: Synchronous response from asynchronous processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kubernetes, apache-kafka, distributed-computing

[image]

1. A Web API receives a customer's credit card request data at an endpoint.
2. The endpoint sends a message with this data to the Kafka.
3. Several pods/containers will be connected to Kafka in this topic for processing each request in parallel. The application requires high asynchronous processing power.
4. After sending the request, the frontend will display a progress bar and will wait. It needs a response as soon as the process is finished.

**The question**

> How to return in the same call to this endpoint the result of a
>   processing that will be done in another web API project?
>   (asynchronous)

**What I thought**

- Creating a topic in Kafka to be notified of the completion of processing and subscribe to it in the endpoint after sending the CreditCardRequest message to process on Kafka.
- Using a query on the mongo on every 3~4 seconds (pooling) and check if the record has been included by the Worker / Pod / Processing Container. (URRGGH)
- Creating another endpoint for the frontend to query the operation status, this endpoint will also do a query in the mongo to check the current status of the process.

**I wonder deeply if there is no framework/standard already used for these situations.**

Answer (score 1):

yes, there are frameworks that handle this. 
From a .NET perspective, I have used nServiceBus todo something similar in the past (coordinate long-running processes).

They have a concept called Sagas https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/
A saga will wait for all messages that are required to finish processing before notifying the next step of the process to continue.

If the framework is not useful, hopefully, the processes are and you can discover how to implement in a Kafka/Mongo environment.